# 503 Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable (Mod_wsgi, Apache, Django) 

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, django, mod-wsgi

I followed the tutorial to mount a Djando application on Apache [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango).
The Django project was created under its own directory in /opt. Any suggestions or other tutorials I can use? I reviewed few tutorials on the Django site with no success. The application does not serve any static pages, just receives requests. However, we did setup a test file to check if the app is working in  urls.py. I get a 404 error.

Error:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or > capacity problems. Please try again later.

Here is the current configuration is set: app.wsgi

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/opt/<APPLICATION>')
sys.path.append('<PATH TO PYTHON INSTALL>/django')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '<APPLICATION>.settings_production'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

- OS: CentOS
- Python: 2.7
- Framework: Django
- Mod: MOD_WSGI
- WebServer: Apache

Apache Entries:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess server threads=25 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup server

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/<APPLICATION>/<APPLICATION>.wsgi

<Directory /opt/<APPLICATION>>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything or if I can supply any other data.

After further research I found the issue is with creating a socket as Apache may not have access to do so. I tried using the:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /tmp/wsgi
```

, but I receive a 500 Internal Error, thoughts?

Thank-you

Comment: What are you seeing when you visit your webpage? Blank page, <% sometag %>?

Also try setting DEBUG=true in your settings file to see if you can a more descriptive error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (Service Temporarily Unavailable).
I found the solution here:
https://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/scripts/setup-web2py-fedora.sh
At line 373.

```
echo "WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi" >> /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf
```